# How to set different rules to multiple IPs on the same interface?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, firewall, network-interface

I am new to iptables and am confused on how I am supposed to set this up. It looks like I have 2 ethernet cards but I have 4 IP addresses. No prob there. In my network/interfaces, it looks like they are all on enp2s0f0. Can I just change 2 of them to be on interface enp2s0f1 assuming that the network comming into the server is the same as enp2s0f0?

If in iptables you specify eth0 (in my case enp2s0f0) then how am I supposed to make rules for each IP?

What I tried to do is specify the iface in network/interfaces as shown below however iptables shows the destination as "anywhere" when I specifically set it to enp2s0f0:0 and enp2s0f0

```
iptables -A INPUT -i enp2s0f0 -p tcp --dports 80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o enp2s0f0 -p tcp --sports 80,443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i enp2s0f0:0 -p tcp --dports 80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o enp2s0f0:0 -p tcp --sports 80,443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Here is my ouput showing my interfaces...

```
$ls /sys/class/net
enp2s0f0  enp2s0f1  lo

$cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp2s0f0
iface enp2s0f0 inet static
        address xx.xx.xx.76
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network xx.xx.xx.0
        broadcast xx.xx.xx.255
        gateway xx.xx.xx.1

auto enp2s0f0:0
iface enp2s0f0:0 inet static
        address xx.xx.xx.77
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network xx.xx.xx.0
        broadcast xx.xx.xx.255

auto enp2s0f0:1
iface enp2s0f0:1 inet static
        address xx.xx.xx.78
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network xx.xx.xx.0
        broadcast xx.xx.xx.255

auto enp2s0f0:2
iface enp2s0f0:2 inet static
        address xx.xx.xx.79
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network xx.xx.xx.0
        broadcast xx.xx.xx.255
```

l

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I quote some lines from `man iptables`:

```
[!] -p, --protocol protocol
       The  protocol  of  the rule or of the packet to check.
[!] -s, --source address[/mask][,...]
       Source specification. Address can be either a network name, a hostname, 
       a net‐work IP address (with /mask),  or  a  plain  IP  address.  
[!] -d, --destination address[/mask][,...]
       Destination  specification.
```

I consider the case you have two interfaces with two static IP each, since you can do that.
So, if you want to match specific IPs, you can rearrange your rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT  -i enp2s0f0 -p tcp -s 0.0.0.0 -d <IP> --dports 80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o enp2s0f0 -p tcp -s <IP> -d 0.0.0.0 --sports 80,443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT  -i enp2s0f1 -p tcp -s 0.0.0.0 -d <IP> --dports 80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o enp2s0f1 -p tcp -s <IP> -d 0.0.0.0 --sports 80,443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Of course you have to change `<IP>` with your machine IP(s). If you want to allow connections only from/to certain IPs change `0.0.0.0` too.

Comment: Can I specify -i as enp2s0f0:0 like it is in my /etc/network/interfaces or do I  have to specify only enp2s0f0 or enp2s0f1 as per $ls /sys/class/net